# Why don't browsers autocorrect incompatible CSS3 transitions?

Tags: css, firefox, browser, webkit, mozilla

Why don't browsers autocorrect CSS3 transitions? The only difference between the Safari/Chrome and Firefox CSS transition is "moz" and "webkit". Surely firefox could just add an autocorrect feature to change every instance of "webkit" in the css to "moz" and the problem would be solved. Or is there something more?

Comment: because they're custom css attributes. development, testing, not standardized. any two browsers may implement a particular feature, but use completely different semantics, e.g. `-moz-opacity: 47%`, `-opera-opacity: 0.47` (as a made-up example). It's not a browser's job to keep track of everyone else's made-up/non-standard things and try to implement or support them the same way.

Comment: Because they explicitly namespace these things so they *don't conflict* with other browsers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the `-moz` and `-webkit` are for CSS selctors are properties that are are specific to the the browser engine. The selector could be unstable, or act differently in each browser as they refine the behavior.

They don't want to "autocorrect" to the other implementation because the other browsers interpretation of the CSS property could be different. It could cause problems about what CSS property should "win" in the event of a conflict. Lastly, it could increase development time for each browser since they would need to figure out what the other browser engine is doing.

Answer (score 0):

In the end what you want is to not use any `-*` prefixes at all. For that to be possible there needs to be a standard syntax and behavior defined by the, wait for it, *CSS standard*. Then instead of repeating `*-opacity: ...` several times with different prefixes, you just write `opacity: ...` once, like any other CSS declaration.

Vendor specific prefixes are there to allow browser specific behavior regardless of what the current standard says. It allows vendors to implement new features for which no standard exists yet, or to test the implementation of features before committing to it. The end goal is always to implement all features defined by the standard in the way the standard defines it; but you won't get there over night. New features need to be tested as widely as possible to find problems with their implementation or possible problems in the standard itself. This testing happens by making features available through vendor specific prefixes.

When you use a documented standard feature like `opacity`, it's pretty sure that it works consistently across browsers (*cough*letsforgetabout*cough*IE*cough*forasecond*cough*). When using a vendor specific prefix feature, it means you're using a feature at your own risk which is subject to change and/or may not work consistently (yet). Browser vendors don't touch each others prefixes for a reason, they work towards the standard and eventually make the feature available without prefix.